# "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'embed' of undefined" when using custom image in the pdfMake pdf engine

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfmake

I am trying to download some reports in my application as pdf using [pdfMake pdf engine](http://pdfmake.org/playground.html) and I adding a jpg logo image as,

```
var logoImg = 'sampleImage.jpg';
var logoImage = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/a/a9/Example.jpg";
if (logoImage) {
     var img = new Image();
     img.setAttribute('crossOrigin', 'anonymous');
     img.src = logoImage;
     var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
     canvas.width = img.width;
     canvas.height = img.width;
     var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
     ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
     logoImg = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
 }
```

which is given in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/h5b9ycoo/). But when I using a custom image, it gives **Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'embed' of undefined** error when clicking the download button at the first time (check the console). When I run the ode once again, then the pdf will download correctly. So how can I solve the **Uncaught TypeError** error?

**Edit**: It will work correctly if I give the dataurl of image directly as given in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mpsbhat/h5b9ycoo/4/). But I want to pass dataurl dynamically based on image link as given in the first fiddle above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could resolve the "**Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'embed' of undefined**" by providing the image in **Base64**.

I found the solution [here](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake/issues/90).

For more information about PDFMake and Images, here's the [documentation](https://github.com/bpampuch/pdfmake#images).